# Form validation null or space not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a form, so far so good except the validation isn't lighting up when ever I purposely let it blank or put a space. I put "required" in the HTML which does a portion of what I wanted it to do.
Here's the javascript function:

```
    function validateForm() {
var x = document.forms["form"]["fname"].value;
var a = document.forms["form"]["lname"].value;
var b = document.forms["form"]["abbr"].value;
var c = document.forms["form"]["city"].value;
var d = document.forms["form"]["prov"].value;
var e = document.forms["form"]["postal"].value;
var f = document.forms["form"]["phoneNum"].value;
var g = document.forms["form"]["cellphone"].value;
var h = document.forms["form"]["email"].value;
var i = document.forms["form"]["dob"].value;

if (x == null || x == " ") {
    document.getElementById("hidestar").hidden=false;
    if (a == null || a == "") {
        document.getElementById("hidelast").hidden=false;
            if (b == null || b == "") {
                document.getElementById("hideaddr").hidden=false;
                if (c == null || c == "") {
                    document.getElementById("hidecity").hidden=false;
                        if (c == null || c == "") {
                            document.getElementById("hidecity").hidden=false;
                                if (d == null || d == "") {
                                    document.getElementById("hideprov").hidden=false;
                                        if (e == null || e == "") {
                                            document.getElementById("hidepost").hidden=false;
                                                if (f == null || f == "") {
                                                    document.getElementById("hidephone").hidden=false;
                                                        if (g == null || g == "") {
                                                            document.getElementById("hidecell").hidden=false;
                                                            if (h == null || h == "") {
                                                                document.getElementById("hideemail").hidden=false;
                                                                    if (i == null || i == "") {
                                                                        document.getElementById("hidedob").hidden=false;

                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }

    }
    return false;
    }
```

And here's the HTML

```
<form name="form" action="form.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

            <font color="red" id="hidestar" hidden=true>*</font>Name: <input type="text" name="fname" required>
            <font color="red" id="hidelast" hidden=true>*</font>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" required><br><br>
            <font color="red" id="hideaddr" hidden=true>*</font>Address: <input type="text" name="addr" required><br><br>
            <font color="red" id="hidescity" hidden=true>*</font>City: <input type="text" name="city" required>
            <font color="red" id="hideprov" hidden=true>*</font>Prov: <input type="text" name="prov" required><br><br>
            <font color="red" id="hidepost" hidden=true>*</font>Postal Code: <input type="text" name="postal" required><br><br>
            <font color="red" id="hidephone" hidden=true>*</font>Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phoneNum" required>
            <font color="red" id="hidecell" hidden=true>*</font>Cell Number: <input type="text" name="Cellphone" required><br><br>
            <font color="red" id="hideemail" hidden=true>*</font>Email: <input type="text" name="email" required><br><br>
            <font color="red" id="hidedob" hidden=true>*</font>DoB: <input type="text" id="newsl" name="dob" required><br/><br/>
            <font color="red" id="hidenews" hidden=true>*</font>Newsletter: yes: <input type="radio" id="newsl" name="newsletter" value="1">
                                                                            no: <input type="radio" id="newsl" name="newsletter" value="0"><br><br>
            <font color="red" id="hidevol" hidden=true>*</font>Volunteer:yes: <input type="radio" id="voll" name="volunteer" value="1">
                                                                            no: <input type="radio" id="voll" name="volunteer" value="0"><br><br>
            <font color="red" id="hidecrim" hidden=true>*</font>Criminal Record: yes: <input type="radio" id="criml" name="criminalrecord" value="1">
                                                                            no: <input type="radio" id="criml" name="criminalrecord" value="0"><br><br>

            <input type="submit" name="submit">
```

Comment: Wow.. Whats with the infinite if statements? Also.. the `<font>` element has been deprecated for years.

Comment: I'm just not sure how to make it if the first if statement is true or false go to the next one. ...... one moment.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do with `hidden=false`. Thats not valid HTML.

Comment: It's not invalid, it worked before. 
Basically, I have an asterisk beside each field. 
 `hidden = false` makes it visible if the statement is true.

Comment: @Dan if firstName field value is correct (`var x`), then none of the other fields are checked. Is it what you really want ?

Comment: I was told the same thing if I used `else if`. I've tried using a loops. I feel like it wouldn't work...

Comment: I don't understand why you persist on using cascaded if or if/else statements. i see no reason to cascade them.

Comment: It might work but that doesn't mean its not invalid.

Comment: Well, what I want is that if `x== NULL || x== " "` then  turn the asterick beside `fname` feild `visible`.

Comment: @putvande Then what would you use instead of `hidden`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a fast example how your code could look.

https://jsfiddle.net/8kn2hgtz/

```
- formatted your html
- the asteriks is now css
- the validation is annotation is way simpler
```

It can be improved and extended, and jQuery would also provide you some methods that seem to simplify some tasks, ... 
but for a first impression i decided to stay with some simple lines of code (pure html, js and css)

Your code doesn't contain some real validation; so I didn't implement one either.
Search on google or on StackOverflow for some libraries that make your life simple at this task.

Comment: Thank you for not looking down on me.... 
This place is really cruel to the newbies who need help :/ 

Anyways, yeah, i'll look over to your example and try to understand what you did. 

Thanks.

Comment: @Thomas Form `onsubmit` attribute is not correct. Before calling validation function, default behavior must be prevented. So `onsubmit` attribute must be : `event.preventDefault(); validateForm();`

Comment: @MehranTorki You're right, forgot to remove this one. Correct form-validation is not such a trivial task, and I would always prefer a more complete Implementation than what i've shown. And in many cases this exact implementation would duplicate or interfere with the validation lib. This was only a first (and as i mentioned) simple example to give Dan a hint into a better direction than the Code he started with.

Answer (score 0):

Working with the code you've got, you should un-nest all all the if statements so that they all get executed.

Then, you should keep track of the overall result - you could mess about with `AND`'s and `OR`'s but the simplest is to have one boolean which gets modified as you go along, e.g.

```
var isValid = true;
if (x == null || x == " ") {
 document.getElementById("hidestar").hidden=false;
 isValid = false;
}
if (a == null || a == "") {
    document.getElementById("hidelast").hidden=false;
 isValid = false;
}
if (b == null || b == "") {
 document.getElementById("hideaddr").hidden=false;
 isValid = false;
}
...
```

and so on until the end where you simply return `isValid`.